# Weird application error caused by "MultiJson::DecodeError: 795: unexpected token"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm building an application which creates PDF documents with maps of trips created by the users. It has two stages:

- Personalization - users choose points of interests.
- Finalization - users enter their e-mail address, we generate PDF maps and finalize the process by sending e-mail with a download link.

I have a problem with the second stage of the process. I get an error when requesting to generate a PDF.

In logs:

```
app[worker.1]: Starting to finalize PDF no #3384
app[worker.1]: Generating pdf url:/pdfs/new.json?id=3384&token=abcdeyd
app[web.2]: Started GET "/pdfs/new.json?id=3384&token=abcdeyd"
```

After few seconds I get:

```
   heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/pdfs/new.json?id=3384&token=abcdeyd" host= fwd= dyno=web.2 queue=0ms wait=0ms connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

And then:

```
    [Worker(host:pid:2)] Trip#finalize_without_delay! failed with MultiJson::DecodeError: 795: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
app[worker.1]:     <html>
app[worker.1]:     <head>
app[worker.1]:       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
app[worker.1]:       <style type="text/css">
app[worker.1]:         html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
app[worker.1]:         iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
app[worker.1]:       </style>
app[worker.1]:     <title>Application Error</title></head>
app[worker.1]:     </head>
app[worker.1]:     <body>
app[worker.1]:       <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
app[worker.1]:         <p>Application Error</p>
app[worker.1]:       </iframe>
app[worker.1]:     </body>
app[worker.1]:     </html>' - 0 failed attempts
```

From the user's side, it goes like this:

```
app[web.1]: Started GET "/pdfs/3384" 
app[web.1]: OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):
app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pdfs_controller.rb:52:in `show'
```

And the weirdest part of this is that when I actually tried downloading the PDF after about 30-40 minutes, everything went well and I downloaded it to my computer.

```
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /pdfs/3384] miss
app[web.1]: Processing by PdfsController#show as HTML
app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"3384"}
app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2101ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 7.4ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pdfs/3384 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=1ms service=4220ms status=200 bytes=13825239
```

I'd be very thankful for any suggestions. Please ask if something isn't clear enough. 
Greetings